# CORS in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I'm trying to set up my server application with cors configuration.
Here the configuration, but any cors request on `login` will has a 403 response code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler) {
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .cors().and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

}
```

}

**EDIT**
I've solved adding another configuration class and removing beand from websecurity one.

Just understand that the cors configuration has to be configured on Spring Boot and not on Spring Security.

The class I've add is:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

         registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowCredentials(true);
    }

}
```

And the WebSeurityConfig one has become:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler) {
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .cors().and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

}
```

}

Now all works as expected, cors is managed correctly on all endpoints

Comment: Try this: `.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()` instead of `.antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()`. If it doesn't work, it maybe come from the `addFilterBefore` function. try `addFilter`instead. let me know if it works.

Comment: Trye to add: `configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));`

Comment: @veben I did before but the problem was still present, I've added the `*` notation just to cover all the possible options.

Comment: @Ctorres as you can see I solved  in another way. I tryed your solution but It not work, give me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**") //or the URLs you would like to add
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST");
}
```

Comment: The class` WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which I extend don't has the `addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)` mwthod to override, the class you mean is ` WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, but I have a REST API without MVC, so I don't need that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .cors().and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/login/**").permitAll() // this
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: I didn't try this because I found a solution before to read the answer, but I think the added antMatcher is useless, because it will give access to resource to all requesters, which has nothing to do with CORS problem

Comment: Happy that you found a solution, `OPTIONS` method is related to CORS since before sending the real request, the browser sends first an `OPTIONS` request (preflight request) to check if it can or not send the real request. So if the server does not authorize that preflight request, we get either a `401` or `403` error. That's why I suggested to `permitAll()` only the `OPTIONS` method, this does not give access to all the server.

Comment: In my API the `/login` endpoint has to be callable from all, it is correct.
The 403 error code I received has a message about origin not valid for the request, for sure if I make the change you advice, the problem will stay here.